# Slide left than right direction

Tags: jquery, css, animation, slide

I have this animation. It`s working on the right side but i need in on the left side. I changed in css left to right but than is not working anymore.

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    var slider_width = $('.pollSlider').width();//get width automaticly
  $('#pollSlider-button').click(function() {
    if($(this).css("margin-right") == slider_width+"px" && !$(this).is(':animated'))
    {
        $('.pollSlider,#pollSlider-button').animate({"margin-right": '-='+slider_width});
    }
    else
    {
        if(!$(this).is(':animated'))//perevent double click to double margin
        {
            $('.pollSlider,#pollSlider-button').animate({"margin-right": '+='+slider_width});
        }
    }


  });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XNnHC/1907/

http://jsfiddle.net/XNnHC/1906/

Comment: HI @donbenni as like this http://jsfiddle.net/XNnHC/1909/

Comment: And how can i do it when i want the pollslider first seen than hide. The first direction to left and than to the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change both css and jquery as shown below

CSS

```
.pollSlider{
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    width:200px;
    left:0px;//change
    margin-left: -200px;//change
}
#pollSlider-button{
    position:fixed;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    left:0px;//change
    background:green;
    top:300px;
}
```

jQuery - change `margin-right` to `margin-left`

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
      var slider_width = $('.pollSlider').width();//get width automaticly

      $('#pollSlider-button').click(function() {

        if($(this).css("margin-left") == slider_width+"px" && !$(this).is(':animated'))
        {
            $('.pollSlider,#pollSlider-button').animate({"margin-left": '-='+slider_width});
        }
        else
        {
            if(!$(this).is(':animated'))//perevent double click to double margin
            {
                $('.pollSlider,#pollSlider-button').animate({"margin-left": '+='+slider_width});
            }
        }    

     });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XNnHC/1913/)

**EDIT** - As OP want to make button seen first and then hide, please make below CSS changes for `margin-left` and keep jQuery same as shown in above answer -

CSS

```
.pollSlider{
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    width:200px;
    left:0px;//changed
    margin-left: 0px;//changed
}
#pollSlider-button{
    position:fixed;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    left:0px;//changed
    background:green;
    top:300px;
    margin-left: 200px;//added
}
```

**[DEMO - First seen and then hide](http://jsfiddle.net/XNnHC/1938/)**

Comment: And how can i do it when i want the pollslider first seen than hide. The first direction to left and than to the right?

Answer (score 0):

You does not change all params. You need to change .pollSlider and button position on page from right to left.

```
.pollSlider{
    /*...*/
    left:0px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
#pollSlider-button{
    left:0px;
}
```

After that you need to change all margin-right to margin-left in js.

**[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e60mxqr1/)**

Answer (score -1):

just change all `right` margins and `right` values to `left`

**CSS:**

```
.pollSlider{
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    width:200px;
    left:0px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
#pollSlider-button{
    position:fixed;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    left:0px;
    background:green;
    top:300px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var slider_width = $('.pollSlider').width();//get width automaticly
  $('#pollSlider-button').click(function() {
    if($(this).css("margin-left") == slider_width+"px" && !$(this).is(':animated'))
    {
        $('.pollSlider,#pollSlider-button').animate({"margin-left": '-='+slider_width});
    }
    else
    {
        if(!$(this).is(':animated'))//perevent double click to double margin
        {
            $('.pollSlider,#pollSlider-button').animate({"margin-left": '+='+slider_width});
        }
    }


  });
 });
```

---

### [Live Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XNnHC/1910/)

Comment: And how can i do it when i want the pollslider first seen than hide. The first direction to left and than to the right?